# Photoshop not creating vector masks(w/ shape tool)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Using CS3, I'm unsure how I've managed to turn this off, but now when I use the shape tool, the shape does not create/appear in it's own vector mask. It now just appears on the layer directly.

I've been unsuccessful in looking through the keyboard shortcuts to see if I've turned anything off that way, but am curious where this setting is kept. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a photoshop user, but since no one has answered, here's my stab:

In the options bar there are three modes you can select.  You probably want "Shape Layers" (A), but you probably are in "Paths" (B) or "Fill Pixels" (C).

[image]

Taken from: [Adobe CS3 Drawing Modes Help](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WS91559667-6EAB-4bd4-9D22-3C5C17CB68F7.html)